# raspberry pi3 servo blaster question

Tags: servo

I run this code on Python 3 but it gives an error on echo 0, and echo 1.

Can any one can correct this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#go to starting possition
echo 0=60 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
echo 1=135 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step1.jpg

echo 0=240 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step2.jpg

echo 0=130 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step3.jpg

echo 0=60 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
echo 1=60 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step4.jpg

echo 1=140 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step5.jpg

echo 1=220 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step6.jpg

echo 1=135 > /dev/servoblaster
sleep 1
raspistill -o step7.jpg
```

Comment: Could you cut&paste the text you enter and the error response?

Answer (score 1):

This is not python, it's a bash script.

I am not sure what the file's name is, but on the command line you should run:

```
sudo chmod +x FILENAME
sudo sh FILENAME
```

And that should run it...

Comment: Why to run the script with `sudo`?

Comment: You need to run it as an admin. If it works without it great, but my go-to on RaspPi's is to use sudo